# Mac OS X Program to Sort Files Into Folders for Burning?

Tags: macos, dvd, archiving, burning

So I have 90 GB of photos from an event that I'm going to make contact sheets for and put onto DVD. It's sorted by photographer and by subject. Normally what I do is make folders for each disc, then arrange the photos in the discs while still in the photographer/subject subfolders, arranging as needed, then once I'm done I just burn discs, make the contact sheets, put into the binder, etc.

But I'm thinking there's probably a program out there that will do the sorting for me, but without destroying my photo organization. I'm using Mac OS X and do the burning out of Finder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swiss army knife of folder structuring based on various criteria, especially optimised for photography workflows:

[image]

[The Big Mean folder Machine](http://www.publicspace.net/BigMeanFolderMachine/index.html)

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could create Smart Folders (OS X version of saved spotlight searches) and put them in a Burn folder using [this technique from MacWorld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/142486/2009/08/smartburn.html).

> ...first create a burn folder as usual. Instead of dragging items into it, though, next create a new smart folder. Set the criteria such that your desired files are found in the search results, then click Save. In the new dialog that appears, name your smart folder, and then save it into your newly-created burn folder.

Comment: Nice technique... not exactly what I need but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The one and only clean-up app on the Mac is TidyUp! It is super fast, and can do a wide range of tasks. You can use it to move files according to different criteria, but also have a search for duplicates between different volumes and set up removal tasks of duplicates. It is very smart in this, if a file has the same main contents, it will see it, regardless different file names or different custom icons. Options are endless.

http://www.hyperbolicsoftware.com/TidyUp.html